# In an IMAP ACCOUNT, how do create an exact copy of a mail message only with exchanged attachments?

Tags: java, python, email, command-line, imap

In an IMAP mail account I want to reduce the size of messages with huge images as attachments. To do this programmatically for a given message, I guess I need to

1. copy the message locally
2. shrink the size of the attached images. (I certainly know how to do this part.)
3. write the new message back to the IMAP store
4. delete the original message

What is the easiest approach to this? If I write an application, I would like to use either a java or python framework. But maybe there is a (command-line) tool doing this already? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, this shouldn't be too hard. There is the `imaplib`, shipped with python. There are good tutorials on the web, e.g., [here](http://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/python-imaplib-imap-example-with-gmail/) and especially [here](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/imaplib/)

```
import imaplib
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('username@gmail.com', 'password')
mail.select("inbox") 

...

result, data = mail.fetch(email_id, "(RFC822)")

...

c.append('inbox', '', imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time()), str(new_message))
```

My example is just to show you the concepts. For details, refer to the tutorials

BTW: You can use PIL (Python Imaging Library) in Python for resizing images.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! It led me further to [`IMAPclient`](http://imapclient.freshfoo.com/). See separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [Thorsten Kranz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14252475/65889) I researched IMAP frameworks in python a bit more and found [`IMAPclient`](http://imapclient.freshfoo.com/), an easier-to-use IMAP libary. It's based on `imaplib`, but presents the data to you in a more pythonic way.